# Wildfly 8 separate daily console.log

Tags: logging, wildfly-8, audit-logging

I would like to ask how could I configure wildfly (8) to have a separate daily console.log (/var/log/wildfly/console.log).

What I want is for the older console log to be renamed with date (ex. console_03-28-2016.log), the console log for the current date would still be console.log.

I will be using the log for tracing purposes.

Thanks